# try/catch in stored procedure ,snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using SQL language to create sp in snowflake. how can I implement try, catch there?

create or replace  procedure test()
returns varchar
language SQL
as
$$

---my code

$$

where should i put my code inside try , its giving me error

Comment: Hi - have you tried reading the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions.html ?

Comment: Hi Check the documentation  suggested by @NickW, for JavaScript procedure the code is  in the try block, for SQL language procedure there is no  TRY block , it only has exception block.

Comment: i can see that , but i need real example

Comment: What's wrong with all the real examples in the documentation?

Comment: "where should i put my code inside try , its giving me error" can you show us your code, and the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample SP

```
create or replace procedure myprocedure()
  returns varchar
  language SQL
  as
  $$
    -- Snowflake Scripting code
    declare
      radius_of_circle float;
      area_of_circle float;
    begin
      radius_of_circle := 3;
      area_of_circle := pi() * radius_of_circle * radius_of_circle;
      return area_of_circle;
    end;
  $$
  ;
```

More on scripting here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html